# Is it good to combine cases in Switch Statement for the same operation and use if else statements for specific operations

Tags: c

I have 4 cases in a switch statement which will behave similar if a flag is set and  will behave differently if flag is not set, in that case is it good to combine the cases and check if the flag is set and do operation and if the flag is not set use if/else statement within the combined case, something like shown here:

```
void somefun(int caseNo, char* status)
{
  switch(caseNo)
  {
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
     if(flag == 1)
       *status = 0;
     else
     {
       if(caseNo == 1)
         //do some op for 1
       else if (caseNo == 2)
         //do some op for 2
       else if (caseNo == 3)
         //do some op for 3
       else 
         //do some op for 4

       *status = 1;
     }    
  }
}
```

or would it be good to keep the each case separate and check the flag separately for each case.

Comment: That's what I would call a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). It could possibly be due to a design issue? And are there more cases than `1` to `4`? If not then why the `switch` to begin with? Or perhaps have the `switch` in the `else` branch instead?

Comment: Yeah, in my scenario there are more cases, which are not dependent on this flag. In general what is the better approach keeping them separate or combining them.

Comment: There is no *better*: anything goes!. In your function, you could *for instance* use *two* switch statements, the first one setting the state and returning early, the second one doing the actual work. and setting the state. This would avoid the if/else.

Comment: This sort of thing *can* be okay, but your example is pretty extreme.  (As presented, there's no need for the outer `switch` at all.)  Can you test for the `flag == 1` case before you even enter the switch?  (Also, as a point of style, flag arguments are often -- though certainly not always -- a sign that you've got something arranged wrong.  Do you really need `somefun` to do different things depending on the value of `flag`?  Or can you rearrange things so that `somefun` always does exactly one thing, with the exception somewhere else?)

Comment: I wouldn't say it's "good".  It's okay, in relatively unusual circumstances, when other arrangements would be even worse -- in other words, it's a compromise.  In the example you've presented, I suspect it's basically not even okay, but I'd have to see more of your code to be sure.